# How can I trim a string starting with a specific expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

How do I find and delete the `utm_content` parameter from all the urls in a file using Notepad++?

Sample data:

```
http://example.com/content1.html?utm_content=product1
http://example.com/abc2.html?utm_content=homepage
http://example.com/test/?utm_content=sku1234
http://example.com/runapp?utm_content=31231KS
http://example.com/blabla?utm_content=nl-laptops-tablets
```

Desired result:

```
http://example.com/content1.html
http://example.com/abc2.html
http://example.com/test/
http://example.com/runapp
http://example.com/blabla
```

Note: As I understand Notepad++ regular expressions use the standard PCRE (Perl) syntax.

Comment: This isn't a programming question as you're just dealing with the text editor; as such I believe it belongs on Super User.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Notepad++ is mostly used by programmers, so the question is just fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: if it were directly related to coding (manipulating code) I'd agree that it does still belong here, but when it's just working with what to all visible intents is just a list of URLs, it feels to me like it doesn't belong here. But it doesn't not belong strongly enough to make a *big* fuss over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your needs:

search for:

```
\?utm_content=.*?"
```

and replace with `"`

Comment: That selects everything until a line break. the sample data should have looked like this: `href="http://example.com/content1.html?utm_content=nl-laptops-tablets"` and I need to output this `href="http://example.com/content1.html"`. I'm sorry for not explaining better from the beginning.

Comment: @Bogdan: I don't really get what you mean. The above expression works fine with examples you gave.

Comment: here's the broader view of the sample data: `<map name="meniu" id="meniu">
<area shape="rect" coords="94,1,174,28" href="http://www.example.com/laptops-tablets.html?utm_content=nl-laptops-tablets"  alt="Portables" />
<area shape="rect" coords="181,1,318,28" href="http://www.example.com/computers-and-servers.html?utm_content=nl-computers-and-servers"  alt="computers and servers" />
<area shape="rect" coords="397,0,494,25" href="http://www.example.com/photo-video.html?utm_content=nl-photo-video"  alt="photo-video" />`

Comment: when I use `\?utm_content=.*` it selects everything starting with `?utm_content` until the end of the line

Comment: Is there an equivalent to this expression in PHP?

Comment: @Bogdan: yes, of course : `preg_replace('/\?utm_content=.*?"/', '"', $string);`

Answer (score 2):

Search for `\?utm_content=\w+` or `\?utm_content=.*` and replace it with a zero string if this is the only one parameter.

Comment: This works partially: `\?utm_content=\w+`. But if I have a parameter that includes the `-` character such as this one: `?utm_content=nl-laptops-tablets` it selects the squence until the first `-`

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Because the OP wasn't specific enough, how the whole URL might be looking.

Comment: @Bogdan Correct. My answer handles the examples very strictly! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use standard Search & Replace (Ctrl + R)

Edit:

**Search:** utm_content

**Replace:**

Press find and then press Replace Rest.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: The original question of the OP was to vague.
A simple Search and Replace was sufficient for the original question.
The edited question is more clear, and does require RegEx